# Protagonist who can find a weak link which causes a chain reaction destroying a society

Tags: story-identification

Protagonist is one that can find the one crucial link in society /community that if destroyed can start a chain reaction resulting in destroying that society.

Setting is a world which has some weird religious/? society which is under observation by a group of people from higher tech society staying there to study the society.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like M.A. Foster's The Morphodite trilogy.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._A._Foster

Comment: hey thanks, that was it! lotsa love sri

Comment: Since that was it, I've expanded my comment and made it an answer.

Comment: Since this seems to be the answer you were looking for, could you go ahead and accept it?

Comment: Later question on this series has slightly more detail and a formally-accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

M.A. Foster's Morphodite Trilogy

1. The Morphodite (1981)
2. Transformer (1983)
3. Preserver (1985)

From the Wikipedia synopsis:

In The Morphodite, we discover the initial character, Rael, as a fearsome assassin who has never been unleashed upon the world. He (as he/she then is) is caged in "The Mask Factory", and his captors fear him much more than any of their other creations. Rael is not a bioengineered assassin: he/she instead initiates Change through a form of meditation. The process of Change is similar to a small death without the "ever after" aspects of it, and is quite painful—not something Rael does lightly. Additionally, Change involves a forced decrease in age of 10 to 20 years, limiting the number of Changes possible in a short period of time. We discover why Rael is so feared shortly after "his" introduction--"he" has evolved a scientific method of predicting or divining the future. Most particularly, this art can identify the single person whose death would precipitate a societal change. That art is elaborated in Transformer, but in brief it is likened to a version of the I Ching that is both scientifically rigorous and orders of magnitude more complex. This divination tool is referred to as "the art" through the books. The Morphodite depicts Rael's unleashing on the unchanging world of Oerlikon and the changes he/she thereby unleashes upon it.